# An unusually tricky Galaxy

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

#### Background

I love [Simon Tatham's Puzzles](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/), especially for killing the odd few minutes. One of the available puzzles is [Galaxies](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/doc/galaxies.html), based on [Tentai Show](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/tentai_show/). I can usually solve these in anywhere from 30 seconds to a few minutes, but I stumbled upon one that has had me scratching my head for (off and on) the better part of an hour or more. Since this one seems unusually tricky, I thought I'd share it...

#### Puzzle

[image: the puzzle]

- Add line segments along any grid edge to form non-overlapping regions.
- Each region must contain exactly one circle.
- Each region must have two-fold rotational symmetry about its circle.
- The entire grid must be filled with regions.

[Play online](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/galaxies.html#9x9:jexfctzndtfbmvzpzgdddwf) or with an offline client using Game ID `9x9:jexfctzndtfbmvzpzgdddwf`.

#### Notes

I haven't yet given up on this, so I'm not going to look at solutions until I've either cracked it or thrown in the towel. Please be patient.

To be accepted, an answer **must** show *how* to solve the puzzle, preferably without bifurcation, and preferably using only the tools in the app. (That is, you can mark that a particular square is associated with a particular circle, but you can't mark a set of *possible* circles. Beware, however, that I'm not sure it's possible to solve under such limitations.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That was a nice one. Made easier for me by the fact that you said it was hard!

Start with the obvious reflections:

> [image: step 1]

The third square on the top row can only be associated with one of two centers, so I choose the less obvious first:

> [image: step 2]

Fill out a few things from there:

> [image: step 3]

Fourth item in row 3 can actually only be in one place, which limits things a lot:

> [image: step 4]

And done!

> [image: done]

There're a couple of pretty crazy shapes there that make it important not to make any assumptions. Tatham has nice back-tracking functions. In general, don't make any guesses. But if you have to, make sure you know what you guessed so you can go back and eliminate that option if it doesn't work out. You probably know this already.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, there is no way to solve without bifurcating on either (1, 3), as you did, or (7, 3). Both have only two candidates for "ownership". (BTW, I *did* finally solve this myself before looking at your answer; one reason it took so long to reply!)

Comment: I also found that I had to bifurcate here. Followed the logic around the entire grid until I just decided it had to be the solution because I didn't hit and contradictions. An unsatisfying end for something that took me about two hours! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one immediate deduction. Not sure how to continue.

> The tile (6,7) has to belong to the circle 1.5 rows above it.
>
>  [image]

> This cuts off access to (3,7) for all other circles, so that this circle sits in a 2x 4 area.
>
>  [image]

> This allows for some trivial reflections, but not for a full solution without bifurcation.